# req.isAuthenticated() always false, PassportJs + nodeJS + dynamoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to web programming and I have to develop an instagram-like for my school. We have the frontend in ReactJS and now we have to develop a server in nodeJS, using passport for logs and dynamoDb for all the databases (it will be deployed on amazon services).

I'm having an issue right now with Passport, it always returns false when i'm calling `req.isAuthenticated()`, and I really don't why.
Here is my code:
**Index.js**

```
const express       = require('express');
const session       = require('express-session');
const cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
const flash         = require('connect-flash');
const passport      = require('passport');
...
const app = express();
...
app.use(cookieParser());

require('./common/passport')(passport);

app.use(session({
    cookie : {
    maxAge: 3600000, // see below
    secure: false
},
secret: 'khugugjh',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login      
...
require('./controllers/sample-controller')(app, passport);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

**passport.js**

```
...
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
  docClient.getItem({"TableName":tableName,"Key": {"email":{"S":email}}}, function(err,data){
if (err)
    done(err,data);
else
    done(err,data.Item)
 })
});

...

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) { 
email = req.body.email;
password = req.body.password;
var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key:{
            "email": email
        }
    };
    docClient.get(params, function(err,data){
    if (err){
        return done(err);
    }
    if (isEmpty(data)){
        return done(null, false, "KO"); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
    }
    if (password != data.Item.password){
        return done(null, false, "KO"); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
    }else{
        return done(null, {email: data.Item.email});
    }
});
}));
```

and finally:
**sample-controller.js**

```
...  
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), (req, res) => {

    res.send("OK");
});
...
   app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {

    console.log("AUTHENTIFIE !");
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.sessionStore.sessions);
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED");
}
```

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not authenticated, you don't have an instance of connection for you database,there is a snippet for the local strategy when using passport with dynamodb [here](https://gist.github.com/samuelhei/7371e62ae8f18e8811e6)

Comment: I'm already connected to my database where I have a table "Users" with all my users infos. Do I need to stock my sessions in a database too ?